# I'm trying to get the user's browser to "remember" which portion of a collapisble menu was open when they last visited a page and then reopen it

Tags: javascript, html, materialize

I made the front end (HTML) using [materializecss](https://materializecss.com/) framework. I am using their [Collapsible](https://materializecss.com/collapsible.html) elements that expand when clicked.

Within some of the elements are forms which, after submission, trigger a refresh of the web page. Once the page reloads, the collapsible elements are all collapsed. Also, when the user navigates away from the page and then returns, all elements are collapsed.

I'm trying to find a way to 'remember' which element was open. I was thinking it was best to store the currently opened element in local memory and then use access that when it reloads and then use their .open() method....but I can't figure out how to do this on local storage.

EDIT:

adding my current attempt at using local storage

**html**

```
  <ul class="collapsible">
    <li>
      <div class="collapsible-header">first tab header</div>
      <div class="collapsible-body"><span>first tab body</span></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="collapsible-header">second tab header</div>
      <div class="collapsible-body"><span>second tab body</span></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

**javascript**

```
<script>

function activate(n){
  //open collapsible element, the tab # being the variable passed in
  $(".collapsible").open(n)
}
function storeElem(n){
  window.localStorage.setItem('openElem', n)
}

$(document).ready(function(){    
    var instance = M.Collapsible.init(elem, {
      accordion: false,
      onOpenStart: storeElem(n)
    });
    var previousElem = window.localStorage.getItem('openElem')
    if (previousElem) {
      activate(previousElem)
    }
})
</script>
```

Comment: `localStorage` is the correct way. Show what you tried.

Comment: Edited post to add my current attempt.

Answer (score 1):

The argument to `onOpenStart` has to be a function to call. Otherwise you're calling it when you initialize the accordion, not when the event occurs. Also, you were using the undefined variable `n` in the call.

Use `.index()` to get the position of the element being opened.

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    var instance = M.Collapsible.init(elem, {
      accordion: false,
      onOpenStart: function(li) {
        storeElem($(li).index());
      }
    });
    var previousElem = window.localStorage.getItem('openElem')
    if (previousElem) {
      activate(previousElem)
    }
})
```

Comment: I've tried this and also put several different variations on it and no go. Looks like the onOpenStart function is not operating. I added a console.log('string') and it is not executing. Accordian:false is also not working.  I've checked for syntax errors/typos, completely removed mine and pasted your version in. The elements are  I'm trying to look through materialize's documentation but am having a difficult time finding an answer; probably should have picked a different framework since I'm not very experienced.

Answer (score 0):

Try write data to localstorage and then when page is loaded read it.

**Static data**

```
 const LOCALSTORAGE = {
        COLLAPSED_INDEX: 'project-name-is-collapsed-state',
    };
```

**Main logic**

```
class Collapsible {
    _instance = null;

    // ---> Getters
    _getLocalIndex() {
        const collapsedIndex = localStorage.getItem(LOCALSTORAGE.COLLAPSED_INDEX);
        return collapsedIndex;
    }

    // ---> Setters
    _setLocalIndexByElement(element) {
        const index = $(element).index();
        this._setLocalIndex(index);
    }
    
    _setLocalIndex(index) {
        localStorage.setItem(LOCALSTORAGE.COLLAPSED_INDEX, index);
    }

    // ---> Events
    _onOpenStart(element) {
        this._setLocalIndexByElement(element);
    }

    // ---> Actions
    init() {
        this._setupInstance();
        this._setupActiveTab();
    }

    _setupInstance() {
        this._instance = M.Collapsible.init(elem, {
            accordion: false,
            onOpenStart: this._onOpenStart,
        });
    }

    _setupActiveTab() {
        const index = this._getLocalIndex();

        if (index === undefined) {
            return;
        }

        this._openByIndex(index);
    }

    _openByIndex(index) {
        if (this._instance === null) {
            return;
        }

        this._instance.open(index);
    }
}
```

**Initialize**

```
function onDocReady() {
    const collapsible = new Collapsible();
    collapsible.init();
}

$(document).ready(onDocReady);
```

Comment: He has multiple accordions, he needs to know which one is open.

Comment: Updated post for multiple collapsible elements